# uniqBy works in server-side but is not a function in client-side

Tags: node.js, json, lodash, unique, require

My array is full of repeated key values and I wanted to filter to get the distinct values.

JSON.file

20888 rows of :

```
[
    {
        "table_schema": "pg",
        "table_name": "type",
    },
    {
        "table_schema": "pg",
        "table_name": "type1",
    },
    {
        "table_schema": "pg12",
        "table_name": "pg_type",
    }
]
```

Node.js function:

```
//since I'm using to call to the client side, i cant use const uniqby = require("lodash.uniqby") as it will return me require is not defined in the html
const uniqBy = typeof window !== 'undefined'
? window.uniqBy
:require('lodash.uniqby');

let arrayUniq = [];
export const filteredArray = () => {
    var uniqueALR = uniqBy(data, 'table_schema');
    console.log(uniqueALR);
    return uniqueALR ;
}
```

this works on the server-side as it returns me:

```
[
    {
        "table_schema": "pg",
        "table_name": "type",
    },
    {
        "table_schema": "pg12",
        "table_name": "pg_type",
    }
]
```

However, when I called in the client-side, the console in the HTML says that "uniqBy is not a function"

How do i solve this? Anyways that i can filter my huge json filr>

Answer (score 0):

because in client-side the way you import Loadash was a bit different so only the server-side got imported to use loadash on client-side in your html head or body put
`<script src="lodash.js"></script>` to use it in browser

Comment: the script src is pointed to your lodash location you can read it here https://lodash.com or you can just load a cdn version of lodash <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>